# sublime text replace and find expression regular expression

Tags: latex, sublimetext3

I want to replace expressions of the form

```
\theta^\top x_2 +x_1 or \theta^\top x_{2} +x_{1} or \theta^{\top} x_{2} +x_{1} or \theta^{\top}x_{2}+x_{1}
```

or any other combinations of the same latex math command 
by

```
\theta \diamond x
```

using sublime text. Is there a way to do this in sublime text using regular expression? I couldn't find the regex for `{` or `}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `{` and `}` are part of the regex syntax. You can escape them by using a slash (`\`). Something like this might work:

```
\\theta\^\{?\\top\}?\s*\{?x_\{?2\}?\s*\+\s*x_\{?1\}?
```

Let's break it down.

- `\\theta\^` will match the string `\theta`. Note that we have to escape the `\t` and `^` since `\t` is a tab and `^` is part of the regex syntax.
- `\{?` and `\}?` will match `{` or `}` either once or not at all. Again we have to escape the brackets. The question mark (`?`) means this character can occur 0 or 1 time(s).
- `\\top` - again, we have to escape the tab character `\t`.
- `\s*` - a space character (`\s`) *zero of more* times.
- `x_\{?2\}?\s*\+\s*x_\{?1\}?` will match `x_`, optional curly brackets with a 2, zero or more spaces followed by a `+` (which is also part of the regex syntax, so we must escape it), and then `x_` with a one (and also optional curly brackets).

Hopefully this clears things up!

Comment: That works. Thanks a lot! This is the first time for me using regex. Do you know of any good place/link  where I can find explanation for what you wrote?  I don't want to ask simple questions every time I have this kind of problems.

Comment: No problem. I've added an explanation of the regex :) Doing a quick google for regex cheat sheets reveals something [like this](http://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/).